# CSS Text centered inside a DIV

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve something and can't manage to do so.

I have a div with fixed HEIGHT & WIDTH.
I want the text to be centered vertically.

up till now I managed to do so:

```
<div>
   <a>this is a long text</a>
</div>
```

and it will look like this

```
-------------
This is a long
    text
-------------
```

which is great

But if the line won't wrap it will look like this

```
------------
This is short

-------------

.the-div
{
height:29px;
line-height:14px !important;
}

.the-a
{
font-size:12px;
}
```

I need this to be valigned as well!

I tried using line-height and to play with is with JS to understand if its wrapping or not and then changing the line-height accordingly

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

try this example

http://jsfiddle.net/fcalderan/3HBC4/1/

Comment: it works only if its wrapping... if its a single line it will be on top

Comment: no, it works anyway even on a single line. Copy all CSS and pay attention to conditional comments on body tag.

Comment: I did. But the only difference is that in the example its LI -> SPAN, i have DIV - >ANCHOR

Comment: I suppose you are watching the link previously forked... re-check the link I wrote...

Comment: it has more or less the same CSS

Comment: @fcalderan - aren't you missing a `text-align:center;`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fcalderan/3HBC4/ This time you see the right example with divs and anchors?

Comment: IN the computed in the FireBug, I see on the <A> that it has line-height of 15.4PX, but I dont see any inheritance

Comment: @fcalderan - yes i see it well

Comment: I always see the same result - but you gave always the same CSS

Answer (score 0):

```
.the-a
{
font-size:12px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you make the line-height same as the height of div, it will automatically vertical centered

```
the-div
{
height:29px;
line-height:29px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be vertical aligned as well, you'll need to use some display as table hacks. This will allow you to use `vertical-align:middle;`, achieving the look I believe you desire.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/v2wV8/)

Answer (score -2):

```
div a{
margin-top:auto;
margin-bottom:auto;
}
```

Comment: how about padding auto, for the div?